# Assistance with Python Function

Tags: python, mysql

I have very little experience with coding, but I've been tasked with writing a python script to accomplish a task. What' I'm trying to do with this function is go into the directory(directory will always have the same name) and search the SQL file for particular lines. I want to add the _tenant_name to end of the database name. And if the ROW_FORMAT is not compressed, I want to change it to compressed.  Currently, the function is not doing anything, and I'm trying to figure out why.

I've somewhat gotten this to work. How can I write the contents of my old file, to my new file, without it being blank?

```
import os 
import re
import time
import logging

tenant_name = 'tenant_name' #args.tenant_name

def do_schemaImport():
    directory = os.getcwd()

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        schema = os.path.basename(filename)
        new_schema = schema + '_' + tenant_name

        f1 = open(filename, 'r') 
        f2 = open(directory + "/" + new_schema + ".sql", 'w')
        line = f1.readlines()


        while line in f1:
                db = re.compile(r"DROP DATABASE{1}|^USE{1}|CREATE 
DATABASE{1}")
                compression = re.compile(r"ENGINE=INNODB*")


                if re.match(db, f1) in line:
                    line.replace(schema, new_schema)
                    logging.info(line)

                if re.match(compression, f1) in line and re.match(r";","ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;", f1):
                    line = line.replace("ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;")          
                    f2.write(line)

    f1.close()
    f2.close() 


do_schemaImport()
```

Example SQL file.

```
    CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `configurationservice` /*!40100 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

USE `configurationservice`;

--
-- Table structure for table `class`
--

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `class`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
  CREATE TABLE `class` (
`class_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `XIE1EVENTDATACLASSVALUE` (`value`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are calling the function anywhere.

Comment: Ah. Of course. Let me try that.

Comment: Lolx! Also, try executing the SQL statements standalone in the MySQL console, to see if they work there. Of course, if you had used a debugger you probably wouldn't need to ask us, and would certainly have noticed that you aren't calling the function :-)  If you don't use a debugger, do yourself a ***great*** favo(u)r and get the PyCharm Community edition and use that as your IDE and learn to use the debugger. it's the single biggest productivity booster there is

Comment: I'm trying to edit an SQL file, not run anything in mysql right now. Also, I call the function at the very end, I just edited to reflect that. I've been using VSCode and have been trying to figure out how to step into the while loop.